# Basic step by step methods for PCR & Gel electrophoresis class

Tags: lab-techniques, pcr, gel-electrophoresis, protocol

I'm teaching a class how to do PCR & gel electrophoresis soon and would like it if you could check through my basic step by step instructions - it's a while since I've done one. Is there anything there that is wrong, missing, or should be excluded in the following?

> A)    Collect all ingredients from the refrigerator and keep cool (on ice). Leave the TAQ in the freezer until required.
>
> B)    Make master mix by adding all ingredients (ddH20, MgCl2, PCR Buffer, F Primer, R Primer, dNTP) (excl. TAQ)
>
> .......
>
> W)    Take the gel to the UV camera and take a picture. Large DNA molecules move through the gel slowest so will be nearest to the wells.

(The students will use primers they designed to sex 6 DNA samples from 3 species of birds, males should produce 1 band & females 2 bands in the gel)

---

**for the full version see the answer below**

Comment: for one thing you have to add a stain to the gel to see it on the UV. ethidium bromide requires gloves and is toxic.  GelGreen/GelRed is expensive, but is a lot safer.  also remember to keep the mastermix frozen at -20C until use - aliquot it because you can't refreeze it more than ~6 times or so - it degrades.

Comment: Thanks @shigeta useful tip of freezing and aliquot in the mm. I forgot the loading dye is a prepared mix of loading dye and gelred

Comment: Might not be necessary for a teaching lab, but a better control might be to have one extra PCR tube without any template (No Template Control) to assess if there are primer-dimers or any other contaminations. If reagent cost/availability is a problem a control run by one student would probably provide enough liquid to run on 2+ gels (since I assume many of these reactions will go in the same thermocycler it's still a reasonable control)

Comment: So use the defined amount of Master mix and then add millipore water in the same quantity as the DNA in the samples? @A.Kennard

Comment: @GriffinEvo Exactly, and then do PCR on that sample alongside all the others and run it on the gel.

Comment: here's a good PCR troubleshooting guide.. https://www.neb.com/tools-and-resources/troubleshooting-guides/pcr-troubleshooting-guide

Comment: Looks good to me, with the comments others have shared. I think the most important part of preparing a lab like this is not only make sure you get decent results (although with master mixes and the like these days that's usually pretty straightforward), but to know exactly WHY you're doing each step, and to be able to explain that clearly to the students so they understand. Anybody can follow a protocol, but it takes a special person to connect the "how" with the "why" and explain it all in a unified story. Good luck with your lab!

Comment: Thanks @MattDMo I'll keep that in mind, perhaps I could set them up in groups, get them to follow the standard protocol to start with, then have them tweak the PCR reaction mix and thermocycler set up to see what that does, then have them write up the results describing the effect of and explaining why, for example, changing Mg++ concentration affected the end product.

Comment: @GriffinEvo I read the article u wrote on wordpress about this and I absolutely loved it ! Learning by teaching. Way to go...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've run a test following this protocol to the letter...

> PCR step by step:
>
> 1. Collect all ingredients (excluding TAQ) from the refrigerator and keep cool (on ice). Leave the TAQ in the freezer until required.
> 2. Make master mix by adding all ingredients (excluding TAQ) using fresh pipette tips for each ingredient and using the volume specified
>    in the PCR reaction mix recipe.
> 3. Vortex & lightly spin down on a centrifuge.
> 4. Add the required amount of TAQ to master mix (insert in to the liquid) and mix using the pipette to draw some liquid up and down.
> 5. Add master mixes to labeled PCR tubes in the required volumes as specified by the protocol.
> 6. Add DNA to PCR tubes (using fresh pipette tips for each DNA sample) again using the volume specified in the protocol. Label your tubes
>    carefully (and on both the lid and tube).
> 7. Lightly spin down the PCR tubes on a centrifuge.
> 8. Run PCR in the thermocycler according to your protocol.
> 9. Collect samples from thermocycler and place in fridge until needed.
>
> Gel Electrophoresis step by step:
>
> 1. Make 1xTAE (enough to make the agarose gel and to place in the electrophoresis apparatus).
> 2. Make an agarose gel (about 5 mm thick) by melting agarose and 1xTAE in the microwave; allow the liquid to cool a little before adding it
>    to the mold.
> 3. Once the gel is cool, place it in the electrophoresis apparatus, cover it with 1xTAE (just covering the gel) and then remove the comb.
> 4. Collect the PCR products from the fridge/thermocycler.
> 5. Make spots of loading dye on parafilm. The loading dye is premixed with GelRed so your samples show under UV light.
> 6. Add one sample to a spot, mix it by drawing the liquid in and out of the pipette tip, and then carefully add to a well in the agarose
>    gel. Take care not to puncture the gel or spill any of the liquid out
>    of its well. Discard the pipette tip.
> 7. Repeat the previous step for each sample and for a negative control (master mix and milli-q water instead of DNA). Use a fresh tip for
>    every sample.
> 8. Load PCR Ladder, also mixed with loading dye, in to a well.
> 9. Connect the electrophoresis apparatus to a power supply, with negative electrode (black) nearest to the wells containing the
>    samples.
> 10. Set the power to run 80-120 volts.
> 11. Wait until about a finger-width gap appears between the blue and purple bands (approximately 20-30 minutes).
> 12. Disconnect the power and collect the gel carefully from the liquid.
> 13. Take the gel to the UV camera and take a picture. Large DNA molecules move through the gel slowest so will be nearest to the
>     wells.

And got a perfect result...

[image]

The order is Control, female, male, female, male, female, male, ladder. Males have one band, females have two. The final pair didn't show too well on the picture but were clear enough on the screen in the camera room. Thanks for the tips everyone! Sorry the picture is low quality.

Feel free to recreate these guidelines but remember to credit the Biology Stackexchange Community!

Comment: now that's dedication! Thanks for sharing this!